# how can convert list of info to paginate laravel when info dosnt read an database

Tags: laravel, pagination

how can convert list of info to paginate Laravel when info dos not read an database

```
$list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9];
/* how this line work*/
$list=$list->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `forPage` collection helper

```
$list = collect([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]);

$list->forPage(1, 3)->values() // collect([1,2,3])
$list->forPage(2, 3)->values() // collect([4,5,6])
$list->forPage(3, 3)->values() // collect([7,8,9])
$list->forPage(4, 3)->values() // collect([10])
$list->forPage(5, 3)->values() // collect()
```

If you want the full paginator (with `links()`), you're going to need a bit more logic.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

$list = collect([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

$pageName = 'page';
$perPage = 3;
$page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
$total = $list->count();
$results = $total ? $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values() : collect();
$options = ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(), 'pageName' => $pageName];

$paginated_list = new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $total, $perPage, $page, $options);
```

This code is based on the `paginate()` method on the Query Builder.

> ```php
>     public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
>     {
>         $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
>
>         $total = $this->getCountForPagination();
>
>         $results = $total ? $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->get($columns) : collect();
>
>         return $this->paginator($results, $total, $perPage, $page, [
>             'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
>             'pageName' => $pageName,
>         ]);
>     }
> ```